# Solving a simple sparse linear system of equation using csparse: cs_cholsol

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sparse-matrix, equation

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 x64. I am trying to solve the following linear system `Ax=b` by using [csparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/), where `A` is positive definite.

```
    | 1  0  0  1 |
A = | 0  3  1  0 |
    | 0  1  2  1 |
    | 1  0  1  2 |

    | 1 |
b = | 1 |
    | 1 |
    | 1 |
```

I have used the following codes

```
int Ncols = 4, Nrows = 4, nnz = 10; 
int cols[]    = {0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3};
int rows[]    = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};
double vals[] = {1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2};

cs *Operator = cs_spalloc(Ncols,Nrows,nnz,1,1);

int j;
for(j = 0; j < nnz; j++)
{
    Operator->i[j] = rows[j];
    Operator->p[j] = cols[j];
    Operator->x[j] = vals[j];
    Operator->nz++;
}

for(j = 0; j < nnz; j++)
    cout << Operator->i[j] << " " << Operator->p[j] << " " << Operator->x[j] << endl;

Operator = cs_compress(Operator);

for(j = 0; j < nnz; j++)
    cout << Operator->i[j] << " " << Operator->p[j] << " " << Operator->x[j] << endl;

// Right hand side
double b[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

// Solving Ax = b
int status = cs_cholsol(0, Operator, &b[0]); // status = 0 means error.
```

In order to make sure that I have created the sparse variable correctly, I tried to print out the rows and columns index as well as their values to the console before and after `cs_compress`. The following is the result of this print-out.

Before:

```
0 0 1
0 3 1
1 1 3
1 2 1
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 1
3 0 1
3 2 1
3 3 2
```

After:

```
0 0 1
3 2 1
1 4 3
2 7 1
1 10 1
2 -6076574517017313795 2
3 -6076574518398440533 1
0 -76843842582893653 1
2 0 1
3 0 2
```

Because of the trash values that can be observed above after calling `cs_compress`, the solution of `Ax=b` does not match with the one that I have calculated with MATLAB. MATLAB results in the following solution.

```
    | 2.0000 |
x = | 0.0000 |
    | 1.0000 |
    |-1.0000 |
```

Interestingly, I don't have this problem for the following codes which solve `Ax=b`, where `A` is a `3×3` identity matrix.

```
int Ncols = 3, Nrows = 3, nnz = Nrows; 

cs *Operator = cs_spalloc(Ncols,Nrows,nnz,1,1);
int j;
for(j = 0; j < nnz; j++) {
    Operator->i[j] = j;
    Operator->p[j] = j;
    Operator->x[j] = 1.0;
    Operator->nz++;
}

Operator = cs_compress(Operator);

double b[] = {1, 2, 3};

int status = cs_cholsol(0, Operator, &b[0]); // status = 1 means no error.
```

Could someone please help me fix the problem that I have with `cs_compress`?

Comment: I hope your actual system is much larger than 4-by-4 or you're wasting your time with sparse matrices -other than learning about the code. The matrix in question should be >50% zeros (ideally more) or you pay a performance penalty for almost no gain in storage.

Comment: @horchler: the actual system is much larger. I just wanted to learn the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having never worked with [csparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/) before, I skimmed the [source code](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/CSparse/Source/).

When you call [`cs_spalloc()`](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/CSparse/Source/cs_util.c) to create `Operator`, you are creating a triplet (indicated by setting the last parameter to `1`). But, after the call to [`cs_copmress()`](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/CSparse/Source/cs_compress.c), the result is no longer a triplet (you can detect this by checking the result and see that `Operator->n` is now `-1` after compression). So, it is an error to traverse the matrix as if it were.

You can use the [`cs_print()`](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/CSparse/Source/cs_print.c) API to print your sparse matrix.

As an aside, your code leaks memory, since the compressed matrix is a new allocation, and the original uncompressed matrix was not freed by `cs_compress()`.